# is there any way to notify if a new file created in a directory everyday? [Bash-Script]

Tags: bash, cron

i do have a directory called /le/df/er
everyday in it we save 1 file. is it possible to notify me if a file not or not created one day using

```
 if
else
```

what will be the condition?

```
if []; then
        (echo " File is not Generated Today.") | mailx -s "File not Saved today in $x" ******@gmail.com
else
        echo "Save successful today"
fi
```

Comment: What is the filename ? Is-it contains the date ? Does your script run continuously or one time per day (after save) ? Please, update your request. You could check with the filename, the file date...

Comment: You might be able to leverage `inotifywait`  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-ctime -1` to list files created less than 1 day age.

So, something like

```bash
if find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -ctime -1 | grep -q ^ ; then
    echo Created
fi
```